# XmlReader does not have any content - and yes, I called read() and so on

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string, xmlreader

I have an xml without much depth and length. It contains about 20 key-value-pairs.
Now I want to read one specific value. Easy? Well, not if XmlReader suddenly does not want to anymore:

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>My test Title</TITLE>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

First test with xmlConfig being the xml as type string:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlConfig));
reader.Read();
string theXmlString = reader.ReadOuterXml();
```

Result: String is empty

Second test with xmlConfig being the xml as type string:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlConfig));
reader.MoveToAttribute("myAttr");
string theXmlString = reader.ReadInnerXml();
```

Result: String is empty.

Debugging shows: reader is empty. It does not actually read the string.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Use `var values = XDocument.Parse(xml_file_string).Descendants().Where(p => p.Name == "TITLE").Select(n => n.Value).ToList();`

Comment: 1) What are you trying to read?  The XML declaration?  Or the `<CATALOG>` element?  2) There's no attribute named `"myAttr"` in that XML so `MoveToAttribute` is not going to help.  What are you expecting to happen from `MoveToAttribute` ?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `reader.Read` will move to the next node.  So when you first call it, it moves to your declaration `<?xml version...`.  If you call it again, it will move to the whitespace.  It you call it again it will move to `CATALOG` and so on.

So, given that, this would get you the whole of the `CATALOG` element as a string:

```
reader.Read(); // moves to XML declaration
reader.Read(); // moves to whitespace (new line)
reader.Read(); // moves to CATALOG element
string xml = reader.ReadOuterXml(); // reads all of catalog element
```

As suggested, you'd normally do this in a loop:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

That all said, I'd strongly advise you don't read your XML this way unless you have a very good reason to.  I'd suggest you use LINQ to XML, it's a higher level API that handles the low level details for you. As an example, to get the value of the `TITLE` element:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var title = (string)doc.Descendants("TITLE").Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

User the .Read() with a while

```
 while (reader.Read())
 {
       // magic
 }
```